# MacBook Air Keyboard Mappings via VPN Java Client

Tags: windows, vpn, java, keyboard-layout, macbook-air

I'm not sure if this is limited to only the MacBook Air's keyboard, but my company has implemented a cross-platform Java client for connecting to our remote Windows machines for VPN access.

The only issue I've discovered is I am not able to correctly use the backtick/tilda key, as that outputs the same as the pipe/backslash key. Is this something with Java, or Windows? At first I thought it was just Putty -- because that's when I normal use that key, but then I tested in a text editor, and the issue occurs there, too. So, this may not be as easy to fix, as it isn't application specific. But, if anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use mskey.exe on the Windows box to log the keystrokes you're sending to verify that the proper messages are being sent by the HID driver.  The hex codes for the ` key is 0x29, left shift is 0x2A, and right shift is 0x36.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/329329/map-keyboard-keys-in-mac-os-x-unix) was posted this morning and may be of interest.

Comment: Couldn't find it on the Windows machine, and searching for it led to many comments on it being a "threat" -- for its use as a keylogger. Any sites you know to download it from that would be work friendly?

Comment: It is a keylogger, that's the point :)  Sorry, I just figured out that it's part of the Intellitype package: Ahttp://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/natural-wireless-ergonomic-keyboard-7000   After you install, run c:\Program Files\Microsoft IntelliType Pro\mskey.exe

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to log back in tonight. What can I do after I make note of what each of the "problem keys" actually generates? I very rarely log in from my Mac at home -- only on the rare occasion I work from home, or something comes up at night. But, it's more of a curiosity at this point -- especially since I haven't found an answer anywhere else.

Comment: I would say remap the keys using bind as stated in the link above (write a bash script, or even use automator) to map and unmap the key bindings.