# Map keyboard keys in Mac OS X (Unix)

Tags: remapping, keymap, key-binding

Currently, when you're inside a terminal, `CTRL+a` move the cursor to the beginning, while `CTRL+e` move it to the end. I use those key combinations a lot since I don't have the `home` and `end` buttons on my keyboard.

I recently installed tmux, which is a terminal-multiplexer very similar to `Screen`. It uses the key-combination `CTRL-a` as the initiate command. Therefore, I want to remap the `"home"` key to `CTRL+q`. I read somewhere that with BASH, you need to create a file called `.inputrc` under the `~/` directory. I did that, but I am not familiar with the mapping commands.

Thanks!

Comment: My question, if not clear from the description, is how would I go about mapping the `CTRL+q` command to the `home` button?

Comment: bind is available for OSX's shell: http://ss64.com/osx/  but since I've never used it and can't find explicit OSX syntax, I'll just add this as a comment... take a look into that though :)

Comment: sure, feel free to give me an upvote there.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I up-voted you :) +1